# 0 fsockopen(): Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"

Tags: extensions, joomla-3.3.x, akeebabackup

I've Joomla 3.3.1 on localhost, I'm trying to install "Akeeba Backup" from the (install from web under Extension manager) and I'm getting this error.**

> > [image: screenshot]

I've **not** tried to download and upload the .zip file to the extension manager, I want to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you may not have enabled SSL in your `php.ini` file.

If you're using something like Xampp you will probably need to uncomment at least two lines in the `php.ini` file. The first one to check is for the extension directory (`extension_dir=`) and the second one will be for the SSL extension ``.

The directory section in `php.ini` looks like this, on my dev machine:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

You can see there's a specific reference for the extension directory on Windows that you may need to uncomment.

References to the acutal extensions are further down under a section called `Dynamic Extensions` e.g. here's the relevant section from my dev. `php.ini` file.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
```

Further down in that block is the `Windows Extensions` section which has:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**Remember two things:**

1. make a backup of your `php.ini` first incase you do something you can't recover from.
2. you will need to restart Apache after you make any changes to php.ini